# Jenkins independing connection

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

We are thinking to implement a Jenkins farm, the idea is that each developer run the jobs in your virtual machine.

Had thought about having 1 master and each slave associated with that virtual machine using the SSH connection. Is there any way to associate the slave to users and when running the jobs that redirect to your virtual machine? Or what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. you should connect slaves first to the master, there is ssh plugin JENKINS-SSH for UNIX/LINUX SLAVES, Windows slaves you should connect via JNLP and install as a services.
2. for jobs there is in confugration of the job "Restrict this project to be run" option where you should put slave name on which you want job to be executed